# Can I have a specific template for products even if they are standard posts and not CPT?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, single

I'm attempting to manipulate a plugin for a client (the plugin author is unresponsive), and I'm wondering if/how to go about doing this.

It's an ecommerce plugin, however does not create a custom post type. What the client is wanting is for a product listed on the main products page to link to the individual product's full information (i.e. single-product.php).

My first thought was to link each product to it's ID using

```
$productid = $p->id;
echo get_permalink( $productid );
```

but of course this just link's to a post's page with the same ID.

Because products aren't custom post types, there is no difference than say post ID 1 and product ID 1.

Is there a way to link to a single product's page if it isn't a custom post type, or how to create a single product page?

Comment: Try to imagine having no baqckground knowledge of this problem and reading this question. Would know how to respond or even have any specific idea what the question is even about?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Yes. :P

Comment: @toscho : wow... o_0

Answer (score 2):

Filter `template_include`, check if the current post is a product and load the product template.

Example:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {

    if ( ! is_singular() or ! get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'price', true ) )
        return $template;

    return locate_template( 'product-single.php' );
});
```

How exactly you determine if a post is a product is up to your implementation.

Comment: +1 just for remember me old pre-WP3 times, where custom post types didn't exist...